# Why is python saying 12 < 2 when sorting a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

This code usually puts the smallest number in the inputed list in the front of the list, but for some reason, whenever `12` and `2` are inputed like so `Please enter your cards(x, y, z,...): 12, 2` it outputs

```
12, 2
12, 2
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
cards_input = raw_input("Please enter your cards(x, y, z, ...): ")
print cards_input
cards = cards_input.split(", ")

minimum = min(cards)
cards.remove(min(cards))
cards.insert(0, minimum)

print cards
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers. Use `int()` to convert the strings to numbers before comparing them.

Comment: Same reason `'ab' < 'b'`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python compare string and int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are currently comparing the numbers as STRINGS, eg: '12' < '2'.

Because '12' is < '2' when doing string comparison ('1' has a lower numerical value than '2') this means the evaluation will look funky.

What you want to do is compare integer values of these numbers, eg:

```
int('12') < int('2')
```

Change your code to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
cards_input = raw_input("Please enter your cards(x, y, z, ...): ")
print cards_input
cards = [int(x) for x in cards_input.split(", ")]

minimum = min(cards)
cards.remove(min(cards))
cards.insert(0, minimum)

print cards
```